# Load serialized objects when only the interface of the class is known

Tags: c#, serialization, plugins, assemblies, .net-assembly

I'm trying to add an option to use plugins in my image processing application in C#.

I've used Assembly.LoadFrom method to load the class library, then looked for the interface and used Activator.CreateInstance to create an instance of the plugin, a class that inherits from IPlugin interface, which is referenced to in both assemblies. ([like in the following example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/pluginsincsharp.aspx)) Loading an assembly works fine when implementing the IPlugin interface.

I also have an abstract class in another class library for **Image Processing**, I called it **ImageProcessingAction**. Using the image processing library I can create a list of actions to perform on an image and save them in a serialized file, which works fine, but I also want to add an options to create plugins which implement this abstract class (**ImageProcessingAction**) in a different way and thus creating a new action (which also works just fine).

The real problem is when I serialize this list of actions. if I serialize a list with one of the plugin's ImageProcessingAction implementation, it works, but when I deserialize it, the method throws an exception saying "Unable to find assembly Plugin1", the one implementing IPlugin and I just created an instance of and serialized one of it's fields.

I think I can explain myself better with a [picture](http://img684.imageshack.us/img684/3246/92825562.png):
[image]

I just noticed that deserialization doesn't work even from within the plugin! Same exception, "Unable to find assembly Plugin1". perhaps the assembly is unloaded before I get the change to deserialize? but I can serialize for some reason...

Help will be much appreciated, I tried everything and I'm still clueless.

Comment: any chances for the example of your deserialization routine?

Comment: Nothing special, I used [Serializable] attribute.
http://pastebin.com/Nt5A0tYj

Originally I tried serializing plugin.Action which is the ImageProcessingAction object created from within the plugin. doesn't seem to work either way, though - even when I serialize the IPlugin object, same thing - serializing works and deserializing fails.

Comment: Try the solution from the link I've posted.

Answer (score 2):

The "unable to find assembly" with the `BinaryFormatter` could probably be resolved by using a dedicated `Binder`.

http://spazzarama.wordpress.com/2009/06/25/binary-deserialize-unable-to-find-assembly/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't seem to work. when is binding requires? I tried serializing a string and the overriden method was never called. I tried seralizing an ImageProcessingAction from the same asssembly and it was called and deserializing worked. however, it returns Type null trying to bind to the plugin... I believe the assembly isn't loaded like static libraries are loaded. how can I simulate it correctly?

Comment: I found a way around it, but I would still like to see if someone knows **WHY** this happens...

Just like in the link Wiktor posted, I implemented a class that inherits SerializationBinder and overrided (overriden?) the BindToType method. since Type.GetType failed to find types from dynamically loaded assemblies, I made it check all types from all the assemblies and it successfuly found the Type object with all the information BinaryFormatter needed to deserialize correctly.

What's weird is that Type.GetType finds types from libraries referenced statically... thank you.